# Google maps api SearchBox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a friend who is trying to put a google map on his website and would like to customize the seach box to search only in the indicated area. Now I must say that I do not mean to search landmarks, bars and stuff, but the streets and addresses. I saw that the landmarks search limitation is done by centering the map, but about limiting streets, I found nothing. After reading a bit about how you give directions to something, not sure that I can do so. Does anyone know or can redirect me to such a topic?

Example: If I center on London (permanently) and someone is looking for a street in London, if he does not find it, I do not want the search to send him elsewhere (maybe there is a street with the same name in the US or another country).

Sorry it's a little vague, but this is the first time I try to edit a map like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can format the search in this way. If you want to search that street in London for example, you can just do use this format on your search box

```
streetName, city
```

and it will search you the street name in the city London.
If the city is not a constant you can try this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse